# Linear Algebra Transformation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If the transformation is from $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is
$$T\{a,b,c\} = \int_0^\pi 2ae^t+2b\sin(t)+3c\cos(t)\, dt$$
How do I find the standard matrix?

I'm not sure if I should solve this problem ignoring the integral. I think the transformation matrix is $\{2e^t,2\sin(t), 3\cos(t)\}$

Am I anywhere close? Thanks

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/317a1c62-c452-478a-a324-1e8d4465d545/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: You find the matrix of a transformation by calculating what the transformation does to a basis of the domain of the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

By "standard matrix" maybe you mean the matrix with respect to the basis $B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) \}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

We could rewrite $T$ this way:

$$T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$T(v) = T((x,y,z)) = \int_0^\pi 2xe^t +2ysin(t) + 3zcos(t)\,dt$$
$$= 2x \int_0^\pi e^t \,dt +2y \int_0^\pi sin(t) \,dt + 3z \int_0^\pi cos(t)\,dt$$

To write the matrix of a transformation with respect to some basis we should first apply the transformation on the basis vectors, so for example:

$$T((1,0,0)) = 2(1) \int_0^\pi e^t \,dt +2(0) \int_0^\pi sin(t) \,dt + 3(0) \int_0^\pi cos(t)\,dt$$
$$= 2\int_0^\pi e^t \,dt$$
$$= 2(e^{\pi} - e^0)$$
$$= 2(e^{\pi} - 1)$$

To get the matrix you should apply $T$ to the other base vectors and form the matrix with 3 rows and 1 column.

$$T((0,1,0)) = 2\int_0^\pi sin(t) \,dt = 4$$
$$T((0,0,1)) = 3\int_0^\pi cos(t) \,dt = 0$$

So the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ is: $\pmatrix{2(e^{\pi} - 1) \\ 4 \\ 0}$

To apply $T$ to any $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ simply multiply:

$$T((x,y,z)) = \pmatrix{x & y & z} \pmatrix{2(e^{\pi} - 1) \\ 4 \\ 0}$$

Comment: ok so would my standard matrix be a 3x3 matrix with 0's as the last row and last column? I don't get how it changed the dimension from r3 to 3

Comment: no, the matrix would be 3x1.

Comment: @user123204 remember, to apply a transformation T on a vector (x,y,z) is the same as multiplying the vector by the matrix of the transformation, if you denote a vector as a row vector, that is, as (x,y,z) then your matrix should be a column vector! if the entries of the matrix are a,b and c you get xa+yb+zc  when you apply the transformation (multiply by the matrix ) which gives you a real number, got it ?

Comment: would my last term be 0 then? and that would suggest it to not be a one to one ratio?

Comment: @user123204 check out the edit I just did.

Comment: ok thanks, just an additional comment, the transformation would be onto correct since its going from r3 to r1 and also one-to-one since the column is linearly independent?